# An error Access to the path 'xxx' is denied

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

Hi i am create a file txt that show error and give link so file can be open.

it woks on firefox  but doesnt work on ie

here the screen shoot

firefox

[image]

Ie

[image]

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("~\Errortext")) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("~\ErrorText")
            End If

            Dim lodt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(lodt)
            If lodt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim filex As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("~\ErrorText\Error" & Session("UID") & ".txt")
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To lodt.Rows.Count - 1
                    filex.WriteLine(Left(lodt.Rows(i).Item("colErr"), Len(lodt.Rows(i).Item("colErr")) - 1))
                Next

                filex.Close()
                lblMessage.Text = "Click on <a href=""../~/ErrorText/Error" & Session("UID") & ".txt"">THIS ONE</a> to proceed"
            Else
                lblMessage.Text = "berhasil"
            End If
```

Comment: Show me code! code. code. code.

Comment: Try using `File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("~\ErrorText\Error.txt"))`. What authentication mode are you using?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean about authentication mode? the share folder or what ?

Comment: Basic? Forms? the authentication mode in web.config.

Comment: authentication mode=  Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To nunespascal for the answer

but It's Still need a permission on iis and folder 
for more detail look [here](http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=209)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the authentication mode `Windows` IE will send your desktop user identity to the server. Your application will run on the server under the permissions granted to the windows user running IE.

You have not granted permissions to this user on the `ErrorText` folder. This is why you get an error in IE.

Use impersonation if you don't want to grant permissions to every domain user.

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

This way, all internet users will run under one security context and you can grant required permissions. By default this user is `IUSR`

You can also specify under which users credentials your internet users should be given access

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN\UserName" password="Password" />
```

Comment: it still not working on iE .i add <identity impersonate="true" /> under authentication but no luck. Must I configure IIS setting ?